# history.pushState allows going back but not forward

Tags: reactjs, react-router, browser-history

I am using history.pushState in React upon changing some data in the page... I am observing some weird behaviour after this:

So, the scenario could be something like current url `localhost`, updated URL upon some action and history.pushState => `localhost/city` and some search action could be... `localhost/city/search`, when I click back button in the browser from this `localhost/city/search` page, it is taking me to `localhost/city` but the forward button got disabled!

Comment: Share your component and react-router code.

Comment: @hazardous I am not actually using react-router.. but express router, I'm implementing Server side rendering and the URLs are present in the server side code as well

Comment: You need to share code. Its not very clear how history.pushState has anything to do with SSR.